# How to encode a categorical variable in sklearn?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm trying to use the car evaluation dataset from the UCI repository and I wonder whether there is a convenient way to binarize categorical variables in sklearn. One approach would be to use the DictVectorizer of LabelBinarizer but here I'm getting k different features whereas you should have just k-1 in order to avoid collinearization. 
    I guess I could write my own function and drop one column but this bookkeeping is tedious, is there an easy way to perform such transformations and get as a result a sparse matrix?

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you prefer k-1 features over k? Having k features makes the interpretation of coefficients (say in a linear model) much easier and might promote sparse features.

Comment: I was trying to find the relevance of coefficients and ran into collinearity problems http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicollinearity

Comment: I guess I'm not enough into the statistics side of things to see why this would be a problem. I would imagine the k feature coding to give much more meaningful results in terms of feature relevance than any other coding method.

Comment: using k features results in a non-identifiable model

Answer (score 15, accepted):

DictVectorizer is the recommended way to generate a one-hot encoding of categorical variables; you can use the `sparse` argument to create a sparse CSR matrix instead of a dense numpy array. I usually don't care about multicollinearity and I haven't noticed a problem with the approaches that I tend to use (i.e. LinearSVC, SGDClassifier, Tree-based methods).

It shouldn't be a problem to patch the DictVectorizer to drop one column per categorical feature - you simple need to remove one term from `DictVectorizer.vocabulary` at the end of the `fit` method. (Pull requests are always welcome!)

Comment: Is there any particular reason you recommend DictVectorizer over OneHotEncoder class?

Comment: DictVectorizer is more general - OneHotEncoder input is restricted to columns of integers representing categories. DictVectorizer also deals with textual categorical values. On the other hand, if all you have is integer categories in the first place, OneHotEncoder seems like the simplest choice.

Comment: But in order to use DictVectorizer, I would need to convert the array to a list of dictionaries with each dictionary in the list corresponding to a row in the array. This seems like a hack. Why can't I just pass an array into DictVectorizer?

Answer (score 31):

if your data is a pandas DataFrame, then you can simply call get_dummies.
Assume that your data frame is df, and you want to have one binary variable per level of variable 'key'. You can simply call:

```
pd.get_dummies(df['key'])
```

and then delete one of the dummy variables, to avoid the multi-colinearity problem.
I hope this helps ...

Comment: Personally, I prefer pandas' get_dummies to OneHotEncoder or  DictVectorizer from sklearn. Using get_dummies in Pandas often result in more streamlined procedure and less code. Pandas is more about data  analysis and preprocessing and sklearn is more about the heavy-lifting 'learning' processes, as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: The drawback to get_dummies is that it will not necessarily produce the same dummy columns on a scoring dataset (leaving you with a ton of complexity when trying to score a model)

Comment: One way to do this is firstly concat training and test DataFrame, then apply get_dummies, and finally separate training and test DataFrame. This way, training and test data would have consistent one-hot encoding.

Comment: What happens when the model's in production and we haven't seen the test data set yet?

Answer (score 16):

The basic method is

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd, os
from sklearn.feature_extraction import DictVectorizer

def one_hot_dataframe(data, cols, replace=False):
    vec = DictVectorizer()
    mkdict = lambda row: dict((col, row[col]) for col in cols)
    vecData = pd.DataFrame(vec.fit_transform(data[cols].apply(mkdict, axis=1)).toarray())
    vecData.columns = vec.get_feature_names()
    vecData.index = data.index
    if replace is True:
        data = data.drop(cols, axis=1)
        data = data.join(vecData)
    return (data, vecData, vec)

data = {'state': ['Ohio', 'Ohio', 'Ohio', 'Nevada', 'Nevada'],
        'year': [2000, 2001, 2002, 2001, 2002],
        'pop': [1.5, 1.7, 3.6, 2.4, 2.9]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df2, _, _ = one_hot_dataframe(df, ['state'], replace=True)
print df2
```

Here is how to do in sparse format

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd, os
import scipy.sparse as sps
import itertools

def one_hot_column(df, cols, vocabs):
    mats = []; df2 = df.drop(cols,axis=1)
    mats.append(sps.lil_matrix(np.array(df2)))
    for i,col in enumerate(cols):
        mat = sps.lil_matrix((len(df), len(vocabs[i])))
        for j,val in enumerate(np.array(df[col])):
            mat[j,vocabs[i][val]] = 1.
        mats.append(mat)

    res = sps.hstack(mats)   
    return res

data = {'state': ['Ohio', 'Ohio', 'Ohio', 'Nevada', 'Nevada'],
        'year': ['2000', '2001', '2002', '2001', '2002'],
        'pop': [1.5, 1.7, 3.6, 2.4, 2.9]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print df

vocabs = []
vals = ['Ohio','Nevada']
vocabs.append(dict(itertools.izip(vals,range(len(vals)))))
vals = ['2000','2001','2002']
vocabs.append(dict(itertools.izip(vals,range(len(vals)))))

print vocabs

print one_hot_column(df, ['state','year'], vocabs).todense()
```

Comment: How do you handle unseen values in new data with this approach?