# Using categorical data as features in sklean LogisticRegression

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression, data-modeling, logistic-regression

I'm trying to understand how to use categorical data as features in `sklearn.linear_model`'s `LogisticRegression`.

I understand of course I need to encode it.

1. What I don't understand is how to pass the encoded feature to the Logistic regression so it's processed as a categorical feature, and not interpreting the int value it got when encoding as a standard quantifiable feature.
2. (Less important) Can somebody explain the difference between using `preprocessing.LabelEncoder()`, `DictVectorizer.vocabulary` or just encoding the categorical data yourself with a simple dict? [Alex A.'s comment here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15021521/how-to-encode-a-categorical-variable-in-sklearn#comment29094148_15038477) touches on the subject but not very deeply.

Especially with the first one!

Answer (score 5):

You can create indicator variables for different categories. For example:

```
animal_names = {'mouse';'cat';'dog'}

Indicator_cat = strcmp(animal_names,'cat')
Indicator_dog = strcmp(animal_names,'dog')
```

Then we have:

```
                [0                         [0
Indicator_cat =  1        Indicator_dog =   0
                 0]                         1]
```

And you can concatenate these onto your original data matrix:

```
X_with_indicator_vars = [X, Indicator_cat, Indicator_dog]
```

---

Remember though to *leave one category without* an indicator if a constant term is included in the data matrix! Otherwise, your data matrix won't be full column rank (or in econometric terms, you have multicollinearity).

```
[1  1  0  0         
 1  0  1  0         
 1  0  0  1]
```

Notice how constant term, an indicator for mouse, an indicator for cat and an indicator for dog leads to a less than full column rank matrix: the first column is the sum of the last three.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Thought of that, but the feature I have in mind has over 40 categorical values (cat, dog, elephant, lion,..............). There has to be a better way.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want then? You can group them into larger categories? Or map the categories into a some `n` dimensional vector space? (eg. map animal name to 2 dimensional vector space (height, weight)). But if you want to treat each category as its own unique category, this is what you (in general for regression) have to do. And if you assume the effects can VARY by category, you have to have all the interaction terms too of your categories with your other regressors. Maybe sklearn will do this for you behind the scenes (I have no idea), but this is probably what will happen.

Comment: @Optimesh, there is no better way, but you can reduce dimensionality by FeatureHashing, or more complex techniques as PCA, etc

Also, this post proposes the same One Hot Encoding technique.

Answer (score 3):

1. Standart approach to convert categorial features into numerical - [OneHotEncoding](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html#sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder)
2. It's completely different classes:

   `[DictVectorizer][2].vocabulary_`

   > A dictionary mapping feature names to feature indices.

   i.e After `fit()` `DictVectorizer` has all possible feature names, and now it knows in which particular column it will place particular value of a feature. So `DictVectorizer.vocabulary_` contains **indicies** of features, but not values.

   `LabelEncoder` in opposite maps each possible label (Label could be string, or integer) to some integer value, and returns 1D vector of these integer values.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.The conversion itself is less of the problem (I think), my main concern is that the logistic reg will consider the numerical values as a standard numerical value, so if Cat is encoded as 1 and Dog as 2, it will assume observations with 'Dog' have 'more' of that property, while we know the values assigned are meaningless.

Comment: @Optimesh, What do you mean by "encoded"? If you are talking about target variables - there is nothing wrong in targets [1,2,3], LogisticRegression will simply build 3 (in this particular case) classifiers and combine them in OneVsRest scheme.

If you are talking about features - OneHotEncoder will encode each categorical feature in binary format, i.e. it will create new binary feature instead of each possible value for categorical feature, i.e resulting dataset will have separated binary features (columns) for values Dog=1, Dog=2, Dog=3, Cat=1, etc. Look at examples in official documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose the type of each categorical variable is "object". Firstly, you can create an `panda.index` of categorical column names:

```
import pandas as pd    
catColumns = df.select_dtypes(['object']).columns
```

Then, you can create the indicator variables using a for-loop below. For the binary categorical variables, use the `LabelEncoder()` to convert it to `0` and `1`. For categorical variables with more than two categories, use `pd.getDummies()` to obtain the indicator variables and then drop one category (to avoid multicollinearity issue).

```
from sklearn import preprocessing
le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()

for col in catColumns:
    n = len(df[col].unique())
    if (n > 2):
       X = pd.get_dummies(df[col])
       X = X.drop(X.columns[0], axis=1)
       df[X.columns] = X
       df.drop(col, axis=1, inplace=True)  # drop the original categorical variable (optional)
    else:
       le.fit(df[col])
       df[col] = le.transform(df[col])
```

Comment: In recent sklearn versions you can now use le.fit for categorical variables with more than two classes.