# How can I use categorical and continuous variables as input to scikit logistic regression algorithm

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

I am trying to perform a logistic regression on a small dataset where each instance is represented with one categorical (Male,Female) variable and one continious variable (Frequency which is between [0,1]) and dependent variable (label) is either 0 or 1. Therefore task is a binary classification problem. Below I share 5-6 examples:

```
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.read_table('dataset.csv',sep=',')
df.head()


Gender  Frequency  Label
0    Male       0.10      0
1  Female       0.23      1
2  Female       0.35      1
3  Female       0.21      0
4    Male       0.15      1
```

My question is : While performing  logistic regression with scikit's  logistic regression, should I encode my continious and categorical variables differently ? Does either of these variables need some special encoding ? Or is the following correct way to do that ?

```
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
X = df[['Gender','Frequency']] # Features
y = df.Label # Target variable
X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test=train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.25,random_state=0)

from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
logreg = LogisticRegression()
# fit the model with data
logreg.fit(X_train,y_train)

#
y_pred=logreg.predict(X_test)
```

When I do that, does the regression function understands Gender is a categorical variable and Frequency is a continuous variable ?

**EDIT**:
Of course, I need to convert string to float values. (E.g. "Male" -> 0 , "Female" -> 1) What I am asking is "Do I need to to something other than this ? I ask this because I saw something similar [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33976845/using-categorical-data-as-features-in-sklean-logisticregression) but the thread has not been concluded therefore I couldn't be sure about validateness of answers.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I was wondering the same thing and was hoping you may have some insights.

Answer (score 1):

You should try onehotencoding as you are using logistic regression. What you are doing right now is label encoding which works perfectly with ml models like decision tree or random forest but can cause issues in logistic regression as the model might  think that "female" i.e. "1" is more important than "0".

Look up one hot encoding in sklearn or dummy variables in pandas. Both these functions will create a separate column for male and female. Whenever the row will have gender male, the value in male column will become `1` and value in female column will become `0` and same for reverse.

```
Male  Female  Frequency  Label
0    1   0    0.10      0
1    0   1    0.23      1
2    0   1    0.35      1
3    0   1    0.21      0
4    1   0    0.15      1
```